# Using FileField/ImageField with Swagger UI and drf-spectacular

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, openapi, drf-spectacular

I have a Django REST Framework project which uses a `ModelViewSet` to create APIs for a model containing a `FileField`.

I've shared a full example of a Django project demonstrating this issue [here](https://github.com/LondonAppDev/drf-openapi-filefield-issue). But to summarise the key components:

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework import (
    viewsets,
    serializers,
    parsers,
)

from sample import models


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        fields = ['id', 'image']
        read_only_fields = ['id']


class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = models.Profile.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```py
from drf_spectacular.views import (
    SpectacularAPIView,
    SpectacularSwaggerView,
)

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from sample import views


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('profile', views.ProfileViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='api-schema'),
    path(
        'api/docs/',
        SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'),
        name='api-docs',
    ),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py** (`REST_FRAMEWORK` configuration only):

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==3.2.3
djangorestframework==3.12.4
drf-spectacular==0.16.0
```

I am generating browsable Swagger-UI docs using [drf-spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to document the API.

The problem is that the `FileField` input in Swagger-UI is a `string` input, and doesn't give the option to set a file:

[image]

I would like to have a file input where I can choose a file which will be sent to the API.

My question is: How can I configure DRF or drf-spectacular to show this field?

Answer (score 27):

After some digging through the drf-spectacular docs and GitHub issues, I found that the FileField can be set to `binary` by adding the following to in **settings.py**:

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True
}
```

Also in Swagger UI, make sure you change the content-type from **application/json** to **multipart/form-data** and click **Try it out**. The upload button will apppear.

Comment: @JPG thanks for the update... For me it's working with `REST_FRAMEWORK`. What's the reason for changing it to `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS`?

Comment: btw, the official [DRF settings](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/) doesn't contain `COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST` but in the  [drf-spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) settings

Comment: @JPG just tested on my project and it definitely works if I put `COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUESTS` inside `REST_FRAMEWORK`. Didn't see anything in the docs, but my guess is that it falls back to use `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings if `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS` isn't defined. However docs do state that it should be put in `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS` so I think your edit did improve the answer. Thank you!

Comment: That's weird. I would like to do some digging into the problem. Could you share the minimal project or create another branch in [this repo](https://github.com/LondonAppDev/drf-openapi-filefield-issue) to have a closer look?

Comment: `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS` that are falsely put into `REST_FRAMEWORK` are not honored. drf-spectacular will not look there for its own settings.